# Setting maximum numbers of characters in number

Tags: r

I want to have number with respect to maximum number of characters. e.g. let's take value 517.1918

I want to set that maximum number of characters to three, then it should give mu just 517 (just three first characters)

**My work so far**

I tried so split my number into to parts : first one containing three first numbers and second one containing remaining numbers by a code following :

```
d_convert<-function(x){
  x<-sub('(.{3})(.{2})', '\\1', x)
  x
}
d_convert(12345)
```

And it work's, but I'm not sure how can I put instead of (.{2}), length(x)-3. I tried print(paste()) but it didn't work. Is there any simply way how to do it ?

Comment: What would be your expected output exactly for 12345? and for 517.1918 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `signif` which rounds a number to a given number of significant digits.

```
> signif(517.1918, 3)
[1] 517
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood what want, but you can try this:

```
d_convert2 <-function(x, digits=3){
  x <- gsub("\\D", "", x)
  num_string <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
  out <- list(digits = num_string[1L:digits], renaming = num_string[(digits+1):length(num_string)])
  out <- lapply(out, paste0, collapse="")
  return(out)
}


> d_convert2(12345)
$digits
[1] "123"

$renaming
[1] "45"

> d_convert2("1,234.5")
$digits
[1] "1" "2" "3"

$renaming
[1] "4" "5"
```